# Autolayout and dynamic width UILabel inside Prototype Cell

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, autolayout

I'm trying to create a "3-column" `UITableViewCell` where each column contains a `UILabel`.  The two left-most labels are easy to set constraints on, they are fixed width and their text will not exceed their IB-set widths.  The right label though could have a long string in it, and I'm wanting to in effect say, "you can be as wide as you like, up to the point your width is within 8 pixels of the superview edge."

[image]

I've gotten closer to the effect desired by adding

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    ENTRY_LOG()

    log.debug("\(self.frame.width)")
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.destinationLabel, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: self.frame.width - 151))
    self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

  }
```

within the custom `UITableViewCell` class, but this is now having the undesirable effect of disrupting the cell height and overwriting the default lines between table rows.

Comment: Setting the right margin constraint to be `>= 8` does not work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, when that is added it appears to work for some rows, but then on others the second column gets "crushed" out of existence.

Comment: @zisoft See below, `>=8` helps but the compression resistance priority for the center label has to be set higher than that of the right label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this have to be done problematically?  A >= 8px trailing space to superview constaint would accomplish what you need.

With regard to your comment: "the second column gets "crushed" out of existence" - you should be able to resolve this by setting the "Compression resistance priority" on the center label to a larger value than that of the rightmost label.

Comment: Brilliant - almost there - setting the compression resistance priority on the center label does indeed keep it from getting crushed, that along with `>=8` helps.  The view doesn't behave properly until a `reloadData()` is issued to the table for some reason, will have to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the height to be dictated by the inherit height of the cells content, you have to specify it explicitly. The best way to do it would be to set the row height directly on the table view:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 44
```

You can also specify it for specific cells using the table view delegate [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)